# Would an accelerated-time space region deflect projectiles?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, refraction, time-dilation

Suppose a spherical region in space in which time goes faster.

Would projectiles shot at it be deflected away, as light is deflected by a material with a lower refractive index?

Edit: This would also imply that there are angles at which the projectile can't enter the region at all.

Comment: Effectively, this could be modeled by considering a metric of the form $ds^2 = -f^2(x) dt^2 + d\vec{r}^2$, where $f(x) \neq 1$ in some compact region and $f(x) = 1$ outside of that region.  If I have some time later I'll think about the details further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time runs slower in a gravitational well than far above. From this, Einstein derived that light is deflected when it passes near the Sun. He predicted that a star whose apparent position is very near the Sun would appear to move a little away from the Sun. This was observed during a solar eclipse. It was the first experimental confirmation of General Relativity.

But the experiment showed twice the deflection that Einstein predicted. He thought it over again came up with the correct description. It turns out that space is also affected.

The curvature of space-time is the origin of the gravitational force that deflects an object passing near the Sun.

See [What is General Relativity?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYq774z4dws) by ScienceClic for an overview of GR. See [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc&t=2s) for how time relates to this.

Comment: In my understading, the deflection you are talking about always happens *towards* the Sun? Am I correct?
What I would like to know is: if there was a region where time passes faster - as opposed to what happens on a gravitational well - and space is not affected at all, would projectiles be deflected *away* from the region, and even not be able to enter it, depending on the angle?

Comment: Also, I just noticed by this description that "not beeing able to enter it at some speed/angle" is the exact oposite of "not beeing able to escape it at some speed/angle" as with gravitational wells.

Comment: Time passes faster in the region away from the Sun. Light is deflected away from that region, toward the Sun.